# Xcode 6 autolayout confused

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout, adaptive-ui

I'm developing an iPad app and i'm using Size Classes with (wRegular hRegular). In storyboard I setup the constraints has the following:

[image]

[image]

When I run the app, it is build as follow:

[image]

The square is supposed to be aligned at (0,0) however when built it shifts tot he left.  Apparently, the leading space is equal to -16 which Xcode placed the value and not me. If I want the square to be exactly at (0,0) i have to change the leading space constraint to be equal to 0. Here is what it will look like on storyboard:

[image]

[image]

Why is this happening? how come that to be at (0,0) it has to be shifted to the right on storyboard so that it works? is there is any new stuff introduced by Apple concerning this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out something. When placing constraints there is a new option which is always checked for the trailing and leading constraints and it's called "Constraint to margin". You should check it off if you don't want to use it. If you had already added the constraints and it was checked, double tap a constraint and in the inspector uncheck the "Relative to Margin" from the Second Item drop down. It seems that the margin has been given an offset and thus making the square shift. However, I still need an explanation for the margin thing. I'll research it.